# Does metal thickness change with rise in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, metals

When a metal pipe or metal cylinder is heated uniformly in furness, inner and and outer diameter of cylinder increase and its length also increase but does thickness of the cylinder change with change in temperature?

Comment: Yes, just think it as a solid cylinder and remove a small thick cylinder. On heating, everything expands. Hence distance between them also increases. So...

Answer (score 1):

If a material expands when the temperature is increased this means that the average separation between atoms has increases.
So with an increase in temperature across a radial line the atomic separation has increased which means that the thickness of the cylinder has increased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I find the best way to think about it is that, when a metal object is heated, *all* of its dimensions increase as it expands (assuming its not being constrained externally somehow, has isotropic material properties, etc.). So, hole diameters increase and wall thicknesses will increase.